# Does transaction.commit() influence on first Hibernate cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, caching, commit

If we have session instance and then call session.getTransaction.commit(). So does this operation influence on first hibernate cache (e.g. clear it or update)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you create the `Session` instance.

If you use `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` , it will delegate to `CurrentSessionContext` to create the `Session`. The usually used implementation is `ThreadLocalSessionContext` which will automatically clear the 1st-level cache after transaction commit. (see the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html) at here which such behaviour is defined by the [`isAutoCloseEnabled()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html#isAutoCloseEnabled()) and is set to true)

If you use `SessionFactory.openSession()` to create the `Session` , whether the 1st level cache will be  cleared depends on the property `hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session` which by default will not clear it.

The meaning of `hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session` can be found at [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-transactions) which I quote as below :

> Causes the session to be closed during the after completion phase of the transaction. If possible, use built-in and automatic session context management instead.

The built-in and automatic session context management basically means to create the session by `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` and configured to use `ThreadLocalSessionContext`.